# Using reference operator in function name returns notices

Tags: php, recursion, reference

My function:

```
function &get_element_from_array(&$array, $searchValue){    

    foreach($array as $id => &$subtree) {
        if ($id === $searchValue) {
            return $subtree;
        }

        if (isset($subtree['children'])) {
            $subsearch = &$this->get_element_from_array($subtree['children'], $searchValue);

            if ($subsearch !== false) {
                return $subsearch;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have an array like this:

```
$table = [
1 => [
    'id' => 1,
    'children_count' => 0,
    'visited' => 1,
    'children_visited' => 0
],
2 => [
    'id' => 2,
    'children_count' => 0,
    'visited' => 1,
    'children_visited' => 0,
    'children' => [
        3 => [
            'id' => 3,
            'children_count' => 0,
            'visited' => 1,
            'children_visited' => 0,
            'children' => [
                4 => [
                    'id' => 4,
                    'children_count' => 0,
                    'visited' => 1,
                    'children_visited' => 0,
                    'children' => [
                        5 => [
                            'id' => 5,
                            'children_count' => 0
                            'visited' => 0,
                            'children_visited' => 0
                        ],

                        6 => [
                            'id' => 6,
                            'children_count' => 0
                            'visited' => 1,
                            'children_visited' => 0
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

];
```

This function is working as intended. Problem is, it spamms me with notices:

> Message:  Only variable references should be returned by reference

Problem is in reference operator in name of a function.
Function doesnt work as intended if I remove &. Notices stop tho :)

I'm sending some data back to POST call after I finish with this function and all this notices are send back to javascript :(

What kind of solution would you peeps suggest?

Comment: `return false;` contains **no** variable. Understand?

Comment: Hahaha, good one! Thank you for noticing that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to always return a variable.

```
function &get_element_from_array(&$array, $searchValue){    

    $result = false;

    foreach($array as $id => &$subtree) {
        if ($id === $searchValue) {
            return $subtree;
        }

        if (isset($subtree['children'])) {
            $subsearch = &$this->get_element_from_array($subtree['children'], $searchValue);

            if ($subsearch !== false) {
                return $subsearch;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: As pointed out by u_mulder, you are correct. Will accept it as an answer.